# tata cdma iPhone 5 model no a1429

Tags: iphone, cdma

I have purchased iPhone 5 CDMA handset model no A1429 and its an unlocked one which i wish to use in India with Tata CDMA sim, please let mme know the activation process for the same as there is no sim slot for CDMA, some configuration method is required to activate it.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings app, get the MEID and have your cellular carrier provision for that number.

CDMA isn't something you can self enroll unless your carrier lets you enter that information into a web portal or other self-service kiosk.

In the US, CDMA carriers still put in a SIM which carries an IMEI for the appropriate carrier, but I don't recall ever having them request that number.

In short, contact your local carrier for assistance.